# Census Population per County Data

Tags: data-request

Looking for the simple time series of the Census data, population per county thru the years available.

Thank you much for anyone who has this data, or can link to the right source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Census County Population Census Counts 1900-90 found here:

https://www.census.gov/population/www/censusdata/cencounts/index.html

Answer (score 1):

The US Census Bureau American Community Survey: https://www.census.gov/acs/www/data/data-tables-and-tools/